# Finding a set so that an element is not in the function of the set which is a subset of the same set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

We have a function $f: S \rightarrow S$ which is one to one.  Given a finite subset $X$ of $S$ and the fact that $f(X) \subset X$ where $f(X) = \{f(x) | x \in X\}$ find a set $X$ in which there exists an element of $X$ that is not in $f(X)$.  If you one cannot find such a set explain why.  I am stuck on this problem.  I tried experimenting with sets such as $X =\{1,2,3,4\}$, but I could find no such set.

Comment: Okay.  You have found no such set.  Can you explain why this is so?  Have you just not looked hard enough, or is there some logical prohibition against success.

Comment: Hint: $f: S\to S$ is one to one, and $f(X)\subset X$.  Together, what does that mean?

Comment: Maybe try using different types of sets such as real numbers and integers for the sets.

Comment: @user278039  $X$ is a *finite* subset of $S$ (whatever $S$ may be).

Comment: @Graham Kemp So to clarify I am saying that integers or real numbers be used for S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is one-one and $X$ is finite, number of elements in $f(X)$ and $X$ are same. Thus we can not have $f(X)$ as a proper subset of $X$. But if $f(X) \subseteq X$, then $f(X)=X$.